# MPMediaPickerController in one view and the MPMediaPlayback in another view. How to?

Tags: iphone, uiview, notifications, mpmediapickercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

Basically I have a three view stack. In the last view I got a MPMediaPickerController that lets the user pick a song from his/her library. The song is to be played later from the first view. How can I tell the player (in the first view) what should be played?

One possibility would be to send a notification and include the MPMediaItemCollection as the object maybe?

Is this a/the correct way or do you have other smarter suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using NSNotification and attaching the MediaItemCollection as userInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MPMediaPickerController delegate:

in your third view controller set the MPMediaPickerController delegate to be your first view. Implement the delegate callback functions in your first view controller.